# Functionality vs. Functionalities: are both correct and idiomatic?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

To me, inasmuch as use of the word ***functionality*** referring to software means the extent of its overall ability, I would write "The software implements the following ***functionality***."  However, I've seen (from my Indian counterparts), "The software implements the following ***functionalities***."  To me, this just sounds awkward and wrong.  In fact, as I just typed *functionalities*, the text box editor underlines it in red.  And yet, I read all over the internet that the plural of functionality is functionalities so I don't know why it should be flagged.  However, I guess that's not my question.  My question is as in the title; are both examples above correct inasmuch as the software quite obviously will implement more than one piece of functionality?

**Edit**
Based on the comments below, let me rephrase my titular question.  Are both examples above correct English?  If so, do they both convey the same message?  The way I'm employing *functionality* only *feels* plural, but that wasn't the essence of my question.

**Edit 2**
It looks like someone edited my titular question which is good because the focus below became too much on pluralization vs. idiomatic correctness. It appears that both uses are idiomatically correct.  However, within the "anglosphere", as Dan calls it, ***functionality*** is most commonly (and properly) used as a mass noun. From the Meriam Webster's Online Dictionary referenced below, ***functionality*** is defined as: "the particular use or ***set of uses*** for which something is designed".

Comment: First, a word of caution: this site tends strongly towards descriptivism, and the most common answer to questions with "*Is X correct?*" is "*Yes*" (and, frequently, "***Yes!***"), so long as "*X*" was comprehensible to speaker and audience. With that said ... "*functionalities*" makes me (Dan) shudder.

Comment: Welcome Thomas! Business English and especially promotional materials Love To Overemphasize Their Importance. It doesn't sound powerful enough to say "The software does x, y, and z."  Why use simple words when you can Untilitize the Full-Featured functionalities of Biz-speak to impress your customers and especially oneself asa writer. (While meanwhile all the rest of notice the Language Emperor has no clothes.)

Comment: @HowardPautz, to my ear, "functionalities" doesn't sound so much like "*commercialese*" as Indian English.  Which, given India has 100M+ ESL speakers today, and a growth rate far surpassing the rest of the anglosphere combined, means "*functionalities*" will probably be proper, standard usage in 5 years or so :)

Comment: @DanBron 100M+ pending purveyors of functional functionalities ... yikes! you ain't the only one shuddering ! :-P

Comment: To answer the question in the title very briefly: no, both are not correct pluralisations, because _functionality_ is not a pluralisation at all. _Functionalities_ is the correct pluralisation of _functionality_. Whether or not your Indian colleagues are using _functionalities_ in a way that makes sense is a different matter, but if the context calls for a plural, _functionalities_ will be it; for example, in something like “In this episode, we compare the functionalities and designs of several popular brands of kitchenware”, the plural is fine (though a singular would be possible also).

Comment: Both *functionality* as well as *functionalities* **can** be used depending on context. They are both correct, grammatical and make sense in appropriate context.

Comment: *functionality* is **not** plural, it can be seen as a mass noun, though. It can have a plural form as well. *n, pl* **-ities** TFD: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/functionalities

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google defines *functionality* as the range of operations that can be run on a computer or other electronic system, so we would expect either "functions" or "functionality."  The arguable exception would be if we were referring to multiple systems, each with a different functionality.

Comment: Well explained, thank you.  In the sense it is often used by my colleagues, it is used in reference to single piece of software.  As for your exception, yes I could easily see either being used though I note that you chose *a different functionality* over *different functionalities*.  :)

Comment: TFD http://www.thefreedictionary.com/functionalities

Answer (score 1):

According to Merriam Webster's Online Dictionary, the plural of **[Functionality](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/functionality)** is in fact **[Functionalities](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/functionality).**

Comment: Someone edited my titular question which is good because the focus became too much on pluralization vs. idiomatic correctness.  It appears that both uses are correct in that "functionality" can be used (and typically is when used within in the anglosphere) as a mass noun.  From your Meriam Webster's Online Dictionary reference definition, **functionality** is defined as:
"the particular use or **set of uses** for which something is designed"